# Wordpress Theme Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, web, themes

I've a website slow as turtle right now. Its an WordPress website. Installed WP Estate theme right now. To make website faster;

What I've tried;

- First I think this problem was about WP. So i install cache and optimization plugins but no solution.
- then I tried CDN Cloud services but still no solution.
- then I create a clone of the website then deactivate the WPRealestate core functionality plugin then I see website is very fast.

When I deactivate WPRealestate core functionality plugin website being fast but my contents missing. I asked hosting provider for this problem he said problem is about the theme, website gives this error repeatly like 99 times

```
"PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u9076910/public_html/wp-content/themes/wpestate/libs/help_functions.php on line 2549"
```

and this is the code in the file. Starts with line 2558

```
   $value= str_replace('_',' ', trim($value) );
                  if($value!='none'){
                      $check_selected='';
                      if( isset($_GET[$input_name]) && $_GET[$input_name]=='1'  ){
                      $check_selected=' checked ';  
                      }
                  print
```

Any idea how can i solve this problem? Thank you all.
[www.bestprojectsturkey.com](http://www.bestprojectsturkey.com) is the website.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is line 2549, so why do you paste since line 2558 ?
At line 2549, there is an empty array (I suppose), so I suggest you to add before the loop (let's say your variable is $items :

```
if(!empty($items)) {
 foreach($items as $item) {
  ...
 }
}
```

I also suggest you to use a cache plugin...

EDIT : just for info, it is not the warning that would slow your website